# multiple transactions in one session in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to run/create multiple transactions in one session in postgresql?

```
BEGIN transaction; --tran1
update  table set b=1; 


BEGIN transaction;  --tran2
update  table set b=2;

COMMIT transaction;
COMMIT transaction;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's called a [SAVEPOINT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-savepoint.html):

```
BEGIN;
    update  table set b=1; 
    SAVEPOINT my_savepoint;
    update  table set b=2;
    RELEASE SAVEPOINT my_savepoint;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Perhaps it should be noted that rolling back the main transaction will automatically roll back the subtransaction.

Comment: Unlike tsql, "begin" and "begin transaction" are same statement for postgresql? Is it correct?

Comment: @ArcilTralleis: Please check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-begin.html The answer is Yes